# Python Code for deleting identical values from one column - ArcMap

Tags: python, arcmap, delete, values

I need Python code for deleting all identical values which are compared within one column.

[image: Column where the identicals should be located and deleted]

As you can see in the image there are many identical values which I want to get rid of. 
I tried the delete identical tool but it won´t work in my situation. It could be that I just used it wrong but as I thought the tool only compares values between columns and not within one row.

Does anybody have a solution for me? Python or Toolbox-Tool? 
The identical rows and features should be deleted and one of them should be kept.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  Coding questions here are expected to contain a good-faith effort toward solving the task, with a complete description of the error encountered. "I need code" requests are likely to be ignored (or down-voted/close-voted, then ignored).  Please [Edit] the question to specify what you have tried and what problem you encountered.

Comment: I don't think "off-topic" was a fair reason to close this question. Maybe it needs details, but I don't agree that it should have been closed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a search cursor and list to check for and delete duplicates.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'path'

addr = []
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "ADRESSE") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if not row[0] in addr:
            addr.append(row[0])
        else:
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

Comment: Thank you! I´ll give it a shot and let you know if it worked :-)